# Create a new column in a list

Tags: 2013, sharepoint-server

In creating a list columns, there's a *task outcome* as column type:

- What is the use of this column?
- What is the difference between this column and a choice column?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

- The object of using **Task Outcome** column type is to create
  additional choices for approvers when using **task workflows**.

> A **task workflow** usually only provides **outcomes of Approve or Reject**,
>   limiting how an item or document is handled. You may need to assign
>   the task to someone else, or return it to the submitter for more
>   information. With the Task Outcome column, you can offer a choice
>   column field that lets you select different completion criteria
>   options.

- The difference between **Task Outcome** and **Choice** Columns type :

> That the **choice column type** is used to let people choose from a list of options that
>   you provide. This column type is an ideal choice in cases where you
>   want to ensure that all the data in the column is consistent because
>   you can limit the values that are stored in a column.

Answer (score 2):

Task Outcome column will be used for approval workflow. It has `Approve` and `Reject` button(s).

In Choice column we will create two options `Approve and Reject` radio button or drop-down list.

[For reference](http://www.suhail.cloud/2014/06/create-custom-outcome-options-in.html)